# What is sunproxyadmin on port 8081 and what is port 11059?

Tags: network

I did a port scan and 8081 came up as sunproxyadmin. What is this? Also, it showed an open port number 11059. What is that port?

Answer (score 1):

Port numbers are just numbers - they do not give a definite answer as to what kind of software uses the port on your computer.

Your port scanning software used a list of well-known ports that matches the number with the name of a piece of software that originally used this port. In your case "Sun Proxy Admin" is a piece of software for Sun computers - i.e. most likely not something you run on your Mac.

To find out what is actually using port 8081 and 11059, you can run the following commands in the Terminal:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8081
lsof -n -i4TCP:11059
```

This will give you the command name and the process ID (PID) of the program on your computer that has these ports open.

Comment: When I enter these commands correctly, I get nothing. It just reverts back to the prompt.

Comment: Then you're not running something that has those ports open. Time has passed since your port scan, so probably time to do it again...